# how to convert a json object into json array

Tags: json, datatables

I am getting json from asana that is an object (data) of several objects. How do I make data an array?

```
{"data":{"id":5571422294129,"created_at":"2013-05-24T15:31:50.340Z","modified_at":"2013-05-24T15:32:21.260Z","name":"testProject","notes":"","archived":false,"workspace":{"id":5571305742112,"name":"TestITAT"},"followers":[{"id":5571289325327,"name":"John Doe"}]}}
```

I am trying to put this in a data table using aoColumns. If there is no need to convert "data" to an array please let me know how to use this JSON in datatables without it.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an object and an array? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: please explain what I'm missing.

Comment: Objects have keys that correlate to each entry. Arrays do not. They are unequivocal. There is no magical formula for translating them into an array.

Comment: @user2402595 It looks like you are missing everything. First, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON , section "Data types, syntax and example". Then come back and explain what you want to have in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that complicated. You can use DataTables `aaData` for this. I **assume** your JSON contains multiple `"data":{..}, "data":{..}, "data":{..}` ?

Then, consider this as test data :

```
var data = [
{"data":{"id":1571422294129,"created_at":"2010-05-24T15:31:50.340Z","modified_at":"2010-05-24T15:32:21.260Z","name":"testProject","notes":"","archived":false,"workspace":{"id":5571305742112,"name":"TestITAT"},"followers":[{"id":5571289325327,"name":"John Doe"}]}},
{"data":{"id":2571422294129,"created_at":"2011-05-24T15:31:50.340Z","modified_at":"2011-05-24T15:32:21.260Z","name":"Project A","notes":"","archived":false,"workspace":{"id":5571305742112,"name":"TestITAT"},"followers":[{"id":5571289325327,"name":"John Doe"}]}},
{"data":{"id":3571422294129,"created_at":"2012-05-24T15:31:50.340Z","modified_at":"2012-05-24T15:32:21.260Z","name":"Project B","notes":"bla bla","archived":false,"workspace":{"id":5571305742112,"name":"TestITAT"},"followers":[{"id":5571289325327,"name":"John Doe"}]}}
];
```

**HTML markup**

```
 <table id="test">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>archived</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>modified_at</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>notes</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

**convert JSON to aaData-array** :

```
var aaData = [];
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    aaData.push([ 
        data[i].data.archived,
        data[i].data.created_at,
        data[i].data.id,
        data[i].data.modified_at,
        data[i].data.name,
        data[i].data.notes
    ]);
}
```

**Initialize the table**

```
$('#test').dataTable({
   "aaData": aaData
});
```

**result** :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are exactly attempting to do, but...

If you are trying to deserialize the JSON into a data table you want something like this. This will take your JSON and deserialize it to an object, it won't exactly work with a data table but rather custom classes decorated with DataContract and DataMember attributes. But I think it may be a good starting point for you.

```
Public static T DeSerialize<T>(string strJSON)
{
      T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strJSON));
      DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
      obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

      ms.Close();
      ms.Dispose();
      return (obj);
}
```

Here is a very useful article regarding serializing JSON. HTH :)

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx

Regards